# React.js generate dynamic routes for the same component with different data

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following routes.jsx:

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <Router>
        <Route component={Wrapper} >
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="projects" component={Projects} />
            <Route path="projects/Margam" component={Margam} />
            <Route path="projects/Margam2" component={Margam2} />
            <Route path="projects/Margam3" component={Margam3} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Margam, Margam2 and Margam3 are the same components but just with different data. This is essentially a list of projects which has the same design but different content.

Is it possible to generate routes dynamically passing different data but always using the same component?

Margam:

```
import React from 'react';

import Video from './video.jsx';

class Margam extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Margam</h2>
            <Video />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Margam;
```

Margam2:

```
import React from 'react';

import Video from './video.jsx';

class Margam extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Margam 2</h2>
            <Video />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Margam2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this :

```
<Route component={Wrapper} >
     <Route path="/" component={Home} />
     <Route path="projects/:id" component={Projects} />
</Route>
```

And then in Projects component you can access to the id with {this.props.params.id} and depending on that id you can show different components.

Something like this :

```
render() {
    let Margam = (this.props.params.id == "margam") ? <Margam /> : "";
    let Margam2 = (this.props.params.id == "margam2") ? <Margam2 /> : "";

    return (
        <div>
            {Margam}
            {Margam2}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I will give it a go and let you know. Thanks